# Easier flag to filter nothing in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have two tables T1 and T2. T1 contains a column "name" while T2 does not.

I want to call

```
def get(T, query_name): 
    return session.query(T).filter(T.name == query_name).all()
```

The only calls for this function will be either: 
get(T1, "some name") or get(T2, NULL) - for the second case I want the filter to just be ignored

A solution is:

```
def get(T, query_name): 
    if query_name != NULL: 
        return session.query(T).filter(T.name == query_name).all()
    else: 
        return session.query(T).all()
```

The above code isn't too bad but I repeat this code a LOT (everytime I query) and was wondering if there's any other concise way.

Comment: There is no `NULL` in python

Comment: How do you wish to differentiate between NULL entries and an actual search for NULL?

Comment: Sorry language confusions. I meant None. I guess my question is, is there something I could call filter(.) that would make it filter nothing (like ignore the call)? Like the second piece of code I wrote works, it's just *every* time I query something I have the same issue

Comment: I'll un-delete my answer but it's broken in a different way because you might actually _want_ to filter by NULL values. You'll need to tell me how it's broken for you

Answer (score 0):

Set a default argument. There is no `NULL` in python, you need `None`. You can build queries up sequentially, so maybe this is a better pattern, where you provide a default argument for `query_name`:

```
def get(T, query_name=None):

    data = session.query(T)
    if query_name is not None:
        data = data.filter(T.name == query_name)

    return data.all()
```

It makes no real difference with this example, but it will if you have a lot of optional arguments.